# Comment Variables not working after EE 2.8.1 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, comments, 2.8

We are in the process of upgrading from EE 2.7.3 to 2.8.1 and during testing we have found several variables that are not working or parsing after the upgrade. Specifically, `{gmt_comment_date]` and `{total_comments}`. Total comments seems to always return '0' and `{gmt_comment_date]` doesn't parse, just returning a result like this:

```
{gmt_comment_date format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}
```

To test things I created the following code block on my single entry page:

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" channel="tmo_articles" paginate_base="tmo/article"}
    TOTAL COMMENTS: {total_comments} <br/>
    {gmt_comment_date format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

The results looked like this when I viewed them:

```
TOTAL COMMENTS: 0 
{gmt_comment_date format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}
TOTAL COMMENTS: 0 
{gmt_comment_date format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}
TOTAL COMMENTS: 0 
{gmt_comment_date format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}
```

Other variables do seem to work fine. `{comment_date}` works in the same code without issue. Also If I use `{comment}` the comments themselves are displayed without issue. I checked the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/#gmt-comment-date) for the Comment module and it still shows all these variables as valid. Does anyone know why just these specific variable aren't parsing properly anymore?

Comment: What's the full context of the above tag, for instance, is it nested inside any other tags?

Comment: The `{exp:comment:entries}` tag pair is not nested in any other tags. It's on it's own.

Comment: As a workaround I'm able to do this: `{comment_date timezone='GMT' format='%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %O'}`, but that doesn't fix `{total_comments}` not returning a value.

Comment: Our Comment Module says it's currently version 2.3.2, is that the current one?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm unsure where to go there, you may have discovered a bug, or there may be some interaction with a third-party extension that is interfering. I'd recommend filing a [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs) so our engineers can take a closer look.

Comment: Bug report submitted here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just closing the loop. I did file a [bug report here](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20447/some-comment-variables-not-working-after-ee-2.8.1-upgrade) and it was accepted.